# Inline editing with dynamic validation, combine two style classes

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable, error-messages, inline-editing

I'm using this datatable and validating the errors and it was working, until I put the 'slds-cell-edit' in the column, the validation works and the message are show, but the field don't have the border color red, I would like to know how to have both, the 'slds-cell-edit' and the border color red when a error ocurrs

```
   { label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', editable: true, sortable: true, type: 'number', initialWidth: 60, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'slds-cell-edit'} } }


    <lightning-datatable
         key-field="id"
         data={data}
         hide-checkbox-column
         show-row-number-column                    
         suppress-bottom-bar
         columns={columns}
         oncellchange ={handleSave}
         draft-values={draftValues} 
         errors={errors}>
   </lightning-datatable>

handleSave(event) {
        this.saveDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        var rowErrorMessages = [];
        var rowErrorFieldNames = [];
        var rowsError = {};
        rowErrorMessages.push('Enter a valid number. Number cannot be less then 100 $.');
        rowErrorFieldNames.push('amount');

        rowsError[this.saveDraftValues[0].id] = {
            messages: rowErrorMessages,
            fieldNames: rowErrorFieldNames,
            title: 'We found 1 error.'
        };
         if (this.saveDraftValues[0].amount <'1000') {
            this.errors = {
                rows: rowsError
            }           
        }
        else {
            this.errors = {}; 
        }
  }
```